# What does iteration in Machine Learning mean?

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I do not get the idea of **iterations** in machine learning. Since programming is **deterministic** (as in do the same thing each time it is ran), how can **accuracy improve** by running the **same algorithm** over and over again?

Does this iteration concept have anything to do with **RNN**(Recurrent neural network) - **in a sense that they feedback to the same neutrons more times** - models or **SGD**(Stochastic Gradient Descent) -**where they take same samples of training data for efficiency**- ?

Thanks

Edit: What I mean by Iterations is in this toy app I found on this site:
https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/rnn-based-chatbot-for-6-hours-b847d2d92c43

What the author did was that he used RNN to create a chatbot. What I fail to understand is how does increasing the number of iterations increase the accuracy of the prediction since the same algorithm is being ran each time.

But from @Spirit_Dongdong's post, it seems that my understanding of iterations (as in what is done in each iteration might be wrong), hence, I am trying to clarify what is meant by an iteration and what is done in an iteration.

Comment: The concept of iteration is quite generic, it can be applied to many situations, I think you mean iterative algorithms, so please make your question clearer about what exactly you want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the article talks about is training iterations. This is because when training neural networks, we use an iterative algorithm, typically stochastic gradient descent.

This is done to solve an optimization problem, minimize a function, but we don't know the values of the parameter that minimize that function. Then we use the gradient as information in the direction which to move the parameters, but it doesn't tell us how much to move, so we move a fixed amount (the step size or learning rate).

Then considering all of this, if we do one step of moving into the gradient direction, we are closer to the solution (the minimum), but we just moved a little, then we move a little more, and so on. These are iterations. When you increase the number of iterations, you get closer to the minima and the set of optimal parameters, and these are what improve performance.

You are right that the same algorithm is being run, but not with the same inputs. The inputs keep changing, as the current value of the parameters changes after one iterations.

Comment: Ah, I see. So can i say that if the step_size is large, the number of iterations needed will be smaller (assuming we do not go pass the min pt)?

Comment: @CodingNoobie In general yes, but most of the time it is hard to say what is a big or small step size.

Comment: sorry for my dumb question, but after downloading examples, i dident found anyone giving the right parameter, since this is a computer program, after it finishes running, you need to capture some variable and tell the user that this is the right parameter, no?

Comment: @Abdelouahab I have no idea what you are talking about, comments are not for asking questions, you have to create your own question in this site.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro already did, and people dident loved it ! I just want a simple layman answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260829/explaining-tensorflow-for-programmer-and-not-for-maths-or-stats-people

Comment: @Abdelouahab Please, you were given quite explicit reasons to close your question, nobody knows what you are asking. You were given resources that you should at least check. Learning TensorFlow is not the same as learning Machine Learning.

Answer (score 0):

most of the machine learning problems are **optimization** problems. such as to minimize the loss function or maximize likelihood function. 
There are different methods of optimization, some like OLE(Ordinary Least Squares) don't need iteration, while some others like SGD or newton's find a direction to optimize and do iterate it

Comment: So those methods (e.g. SGD) that do not fully use all available training data in each run will require iteration to improve accuracy? Those methods that uses all data will not use iteration as it has no benefit to them? Can i understand it this way?

Comment: No. methods use iteration because they assign some initial params, calculate which direction to optimize them, and iterate to make the param values better. some methods use all training data and iterate(Batch Gradient Descent)

Comment: So one iteration means it tries to get the results by using only one data? For example: Given only one set of x and y and ask it to find m in y = mx + c. So one iteration would only mean it uses only that one set of x and y to find m?